# Good book on Exchange 2010 (creating a backup solution)

Tags: exchange

Can anyone recommend a good book on the topic of Microsoft Exchange Server that:

- Covers Exchange 2010
- Give me an understanding of the building blocks of Exchange
- That will help a developer like myself to write a backup solution for Exchange

I've looked at [Exchange Server 2010 Unleashed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672330466) which seems like a good one, but I would like to hear your opinion and/or get more options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Exchange 2010 - A practical approach - by Jaap Wesselius. You can buy a hard copy on Amazon - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Exchange-2010-Practical-Jaap-Wesselius/dp/1906434328

This one review:

If you're about to embark upon, or through work necessity be forced into installing/migrating previous versions of Exchange into the all new Exchange 2010 version, then this book will see you happily from Start to Finish. The 180 pages breeze by like having a timely conversation with a truly knowledgeable consultant.

For those looking for answers and a quick way to exchange 2010 nirvanna, you'll save yourself a good few hours or even days of googling technet articles and surreptitious blogs of dubious information.

My only wish, was that a few more technical authors were like this one. Without prejudice or politics, just simply concerned in getting from point A) to point B) in the easiest most hassle free way possible.

Comment: Thanks did not even see that one.